# Accessing currently visible Fragments widgets from its master activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

Building from an Example activity ( The Tabbed View ) in Android studio.
The activity works by having a spinner showing a selection list and when one is selected, it generates a new fragment - passing a section number to it, and the fragment then displays that in its text widget.
Most answers I've seen focus on controlling widgets from within the Fragment, but my code will be receiving data and updating the active fragments display from the Fragments creating activity.

I'm trying to expland on this, ( at the moment for debugging ) but struggling.

I need to change the text on a new text widget I've placed in the container in the Fragment, 'textview10' and do this no matter what the current fragment showing is.

In addition to that, the required code to change the text is in a handler receiving message from another thread.

The good news is that the handler is receiving the string message - but I cannot work out how to get a reference to the debug text widget, in the currently displayed fragment.

None of the following is successful, but shows what I am trying at the point I need to display text.

```
                      PlaceholderFragment fragmentDemo = (PlaceholderFragment)
                        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("SOMETAG"); // The problem is the Tag is different for each fragment.


                PlaceholderFragment instanceFragment= (PlaceholderFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
                View v = instanceFragment.getView();

                debugtext = v.findViewById(R.id.textView10);  // ERROR
```

The code that generates the fragment is  in the OnItemSelectedListner for the spinner which brings in a reference to the slected item position...

```
      class mySpinnerListener implements Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,
                               long id) {

        // When the given dropdown item is selected, show its contents in the
        // container view.
                 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                .commit(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1),"tag"+position)
.commit();

PlaceholderFragment fragmentDemo = (PlaceholderFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag"+position);

PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment{
   private ViewGroup rootView;
   onCreateView(){
      rooView = inflate();
      return rootView;
   }
   public ViewGroup getMyRootView(){
      return rootView;
   }
}
View myFragmentView = fragmentDemo.getMyRootView();
```

Comment: currentposition = position; // class reference to last created 
            
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1),"tag"+position)
                    .commit();     Has been added, but how to use the fragmentDemo reference to get the widget  - still no luck